# mod rewrite dynamic php values

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My first blast at mod rewrite.  I have this horrible link below whihc takes you to a profile page.  On the profile page I fetch the user based on the i parameter.

```
    <a href="engineer-profile.php?country=<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['country']));?>&area=<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['area'])); ?>&i=<?php echo $row['id'];?>&name=<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['name']));?> " class="btn btn-md btn-bitbucket"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> View Profile</a>
```

I've been trying to make a mod rewrite so the link looks like follows

/uk/southport/23/company-name/

so far I have this in my .htaccess file

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ engineer-profile.php?country=$1&area=$2&i=$3&name=$4 [L]
```

now if I restructure my link so it looks as follows:

```
   <a href="/<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['country']));?>/<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['area'])); ?>/<?php echo $row['id'];?>/<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['name']));?> " class="btn btn-md btn-bitbucket"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> View Profile</a>
```

I get a page not found error.  Ive also tried

```
  <a href="engineer-profile/<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['country']));?>/<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['area'])); ?>/<?php echo $row['id'];?>/<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['name']));?> " class="btn btn-md btn-bitbucket"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> View Profile</a>
```

Ive also checked mod rewrite is on and it is as it works with basic testing fine.  Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Your numbers (23) don't match `[a-zA-Z_]+)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
engineer-profile.php ( example )
--------------------------------
<?php
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r( $_GET );
   echo '</pre>';
?>


<?php
    $id=$row['id'];
    $country=str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['country']));
    $area=str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['area']));
    $name=str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($row['name']))

    echo "<a href='/$country/$area/$id/$name' class='btn btn-md btn-bitbucket'><i class='fa fa-user'></i>View Profile</a>";
?>

# .htaccess
#  required format
#  /uk/southport/23/company-name/

# the following requires that rewritebase is specified, viz:-
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)(/?)$ /engineer-profile.php?country=$1&area=$2&i=$3&company=$4 [NC,L]

# there were a couple of omissions from original - this works now though. The demo engineer-profile.php will output the following

Array
(
    [country] => uk
    [area] => southport
    [i] => 23
    [company] => company-name
)
```

Comment: awesome.  When I use this example and thank you by the way @RamRaider I just get page not found.  engineer-profile.php is definitely there though as it was working before mod rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Your URL doesn't match the route. You need to expand what you allow into the rule.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)(/?)$ engineer-profile.php?country=$1&area=$2&i=$3&name=$4 [L]
```

Comment: cool am I right with my actual link as I think thats the bit I'm not really understanding.  When I link to the page I link with /uk/southport/1/company/  or do I use the original link and mod rewrite rewrites the name for me?

Comment: ive tried both and neither work.  Just getting the page not found

Comment: Nope, it won't convert it for you - you need to use the new link (/uk/southport/1/company)  I've just noticed you have an end slash on the end. I'll edit my answer

Comment: sorry here is a proper link.  if you search for builder, uk, pr97tf you will see where the link is made.  its when you click profile.  parrotsearch.co.uk/search-form.php

Answer (score 0):

As your using `strtolower()` and `str_replace()` spaces to dashes in your link generation, and have numbers in there..  ..your rewrite rule cases should be `([0-9a-z\_\-]+)`  to allow numbers, lowercase letters, underscores and dashes, and no need for upper case values.